# Storing data in a table

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a user table for my website, where the user can see their first name and last name in a table after they register and login. The user detail is stored in the HTML5 Local Storage. Is there a better way to update the table with more users, rather than creating more .

Here is my table:

```
<table id="rankTable">
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Top Score</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="_firstName"></td>
        <td id="_lastName"></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the full working snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/MuddasarAshfaq/r62zmjw4/9/

Comment: I've updated the code and added the working snippet url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that u have stored your stored firstname and lastname as "fname" and "lname" in your localStorage

```
var table = document.getElementById("rankTable");
var row = table.insertRow(0);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
cell1.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("fname");
cell2.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lname");
```

Comment: please open console and type localstorage; paste the output here.

Comment: The local storage works fine, but nothing appears on the table

Comment: your fiddle doesnt contain the table; please be clear; you are confusing me.

Comment: There is a table on the HTML called rankTable, its at the very top

Comment: why is that absent in your fiddle? update it in ur fiddle; I will fix ur need there itself.

Comment: is this the fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/MuddasarAshfaq/r62zmjw4/
if so I dont see the table that u are asking for?

Comment: Sorry, now it's updated. Forgot to save it. This is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/MuddasarAshfaq/r62zmjw4/3/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/r62zmjw4/5/

updated here; this should resolve all your issues;

Comment: I just ran the whole thing in a html file and it works like a charm. I dont know what is going wrong in ur end; What error does the console say?

Comment: This message appears: WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8125/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: This message also appears: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertRow' of null
    at storeUserDetail (data.js:36)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (register.php:97)

Comment: Are u sure that the function "storeUserDetail " is invoked only on click; if so, the error musnt happen;

Comment: Yes I've used "storeUserDetail" as an onclick for my register button.